# fread gives BadPtr when done in a new process

Tags: c++, binary-data, fread, file-read

I have written a C++ Dll which has two functions, one writes a binary file to disk and and other reads that file from disk and load into memory.

```
//extremely simplified code looks like this

bool Utilities::WriteToBinary(wstring const fileName)
    {
    //lot of code

    DWORD size = //get size of data to write
    LPBYTE * blob = new LPBYTE[size];
    WriteDataToMemoryBlob(blob, & size);

    FILE * pFile;
    if(0 != _wfopen_s (&pFile , fileName.c_str() , L"wb" ))
        {
        //do something
        return false;
        }

    fwrite (blob,  1, size , pFile );
    fclose (pFile);

    delete[] blob;
    return true;
    }

bool Utilities::ReadDataFromDisk(wstring const fileName)
    {    
    long fileSize = GetFileSize(fileName);
    FILE * filePointer;
    if(0 != _wfopen_s (&filePointer, fileName.c_str() , L"rb" ))
        return false;

    //read from file
    LPBYTE * blobRead = new LPBYTE[fileSize];
    fread (blobRead, 1, fileSize , filePointer );
    fclose (filePointer);

    //rest of the code...
```

**Problem**
I have created another C++ project which call these DLL methods for testing.

Problem which is driving me crazy is that when I call *WriteToBinary* and *ReadDataFromDisk* consecutively inside same program they work perfectly fine. But when I call *WriteToBinary* at one time and let the program exit and call *ReadDataFromDisk* next time and give it path of file written earlier by *WriteToBinary*, I get a **BadPtr** in **blobRead** after doing **fread**.

I have tried my best to make sure there are no shared or static data structures involved. Both methods are totally independent.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mistake is the allocation of the array as `LPBYTE` is a `BYTE*` so the:

```
LPBYTE * blobRead = new LPBYTE[fileSize];
```

Is allocating an array of `BYTE*`, not an array of `BYTE`. Change to:

```
BYTE* blobRead = new BYTE[fileSize];
```

To avoid dynamic allocation you could use a `std::vector<BYTE>` instead:

```
std::vector<BYTE> blobRead(fileSize);
```

Comment: I dont think I understand, why is it working when called in same program then?

Comment: @HarisHasan pure [bad] luck, would anyway be better if you used a vector instead.